# Swift comparing date is not working and getting wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi I have multiple dates which I am comparing with current date. But it is not working. I have done coding but nothing is working for me. I am using comparison same like [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-compare-dates) link.

Here is what I am doing

```
let todayDate = Date()
let date1FromServer = //its Date from server which is 2020-02-01 09:00:00 +0000
let date2FromServer = //its Date from server which is 2020-02-02 09:00:00 +0000
let date3FromServer = //its Date from server which is 2020-02-03 09:00:00 +0000
```

now here I am comparing All three date in simple if else

```
if(date1FromServer < todayDate){
   //Do something for date 1 
}else if (date2FromServer < todayDate){
 //Do something for date 3
}else if (date3FromServer < todayDate){
 // Do something for date 3 
}
```

> **Case:** Now I have date1 and Date 2 is working but date3 is not working. I am saying this because the date3 is exactly on 3 feb 2020
>   with 9:00 am which is smaller then today date which is 3 feb 2020 with
>   11:00 am , but it looks like that it is dealing like date 3 is equal
>   or greater then today date.

When I print date 3 it prints (2020-02-03 06:32:22 +0000)   and here the time is wrong, as right now on my device it si 11:32 am but it showing 06: 32 . I think as I am just printing it in log so there could be problem of time zone, but on above code it is also not working.

Please let me know what is the problem here.

> **Note:** I want to compare the Date and time as well.....

Comment: 06:32:00 its utc timezone +000 and you want 11:32 which is GMT+5:00. you have to give timezone in dateformatter.

Comment: but in if else I am comparing date objects directly. It may be problem while printing but in if else it must compare date.

Comment: Did you try to print todayDate and date3FromServer and compared them visually? I agree that this is a time zone issue.

Comment: yes I tried it, but it print date3FromServer correct but todayDate wrong. and difference in only time.

Comment: Prints wrong? That is why you need to include proper time zone handling in your code.

Comment: can you tell me how @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 0):

If your server date has GMT as time zone then you can adjust your local date to GMT by using offsets

```
let offsetDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 
    todayDate.timeIntervalSince1970 + Double(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT(for: todayDate)))
```

and then use `offsetDate` instead when doing the comparison